# Google Kubernetes Engine: Error on Health Check

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm receiving the following error when attempting to upload my `health-check.yaml` file:

`error: error validating "health-check.yaml": error validating data: [ValidationError(Deployment.spec): unknown field "containers" in io.k8s.api.extensions.v1beta1.DeploymentSpec, ValidationError(Deployment.spec): missing required field "template" in io.k8s.api.extensions.v1beta1.DeploymentSpec]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false`

`health-check.yaml`:

`apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
      - name: nginx
        livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
                path: /
                port: 80`

Please help! :)

Answer (score 1):

`Containers` should be specified under `spec` -> `template` -> `spec`. e.g.:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ...
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      ...
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - command: ...
        image: ...
        name: ...
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
              path: /live
```

There are 2 specs here, one for the deployment (because you are using `kind: Deployment`) and the nested one for the contained pods.